# How to extract whole userPrincipalNames of the user from AD?

Tags: active-directory

I create a user account with multiple UPNs in AD. How do we extract whole UPNs from AD?

For instance: sathishM@litwareinc.pri/ sathishM@Facrikam.com; <UPN:: @litwareinc.pri | @Facrikam.com>

I would like to extract @litwareinc.pri and @Facrikam.com. Thanks

[image: AD Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

That entire value (for example: `sathishM@litwareinc.pri`) is stored in the `userPrincipalName` attribute of the AD object. It is only AD Users and Computers that separates it.

If you want just the domain portion, then you will just need to split the string by the `@`. How you do that depends on how you plan on reading the object.